# Handle page refresh with AngularJS's http?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

With raw XHR requests or jQuery's ajax() calls, you can use if(!xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()) to see if a user has refreshed the page mid-query; however, AngularJS doesn't pass you the XHR object, so what is the intended way to handle this?

```
$http.post('/foo', data)
 .success(function(result) {})
 .error(function(err) { // this is called on page refreshes that cancel the requests
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular routes you can listen to route changes

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(){});
```

if you are not using angular routes you can listen to the lower level event.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event){ })
```